# Is ansi_padding 'on' officially required for working with xml columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml

When you use SQL Server Management Studio to generate a script for creating a table, the last thing it does is set ansi_padding off.

I've run into a problem where this statement is causing an issue further down the line when working with xml.

The error message implies that the ansi_padding must be on when using the XQuery features, and googling confirms. However, I'd really like to see some official documentation stating this as a requirement, to make sure there isn't anything else we're taking for granted.

I understand the implications of this option and have since removed the statement, but I still want to know:

**Is ansi_padding 'on' officially required for working with xml columns in SQL Server?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is officially required.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188285.aspx

Quoted from above link:

> When querying xml type columns or variables using xml data type
>   methods, the following options must be set as shown.
>
> SET Options
>
> Required Values
>
> ANSI_NULLS
>
> ON
>
> ANSI_PADDING
>
> ON
>
> ANSI_WARNINGS
>
> ON
>
> ARITHABORT
>
> ON
>
> CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL
>
> ON
>
> NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT
>
> OFF
>
> QUOTED_IDENTIFIER
>
> ON
>
> If the options are not set as shown, queries and modifications on xml
>   data type methods will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  I looked around too and didn't find any good documentation on it but the exception messages actually specify that it is required for XML and I suppose that is about as official as it gets:

Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Procedure svrTrgNewDB, Line 11
CONDITIONAL failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications **and/or XML data type methods** and/or spatial index operations.